# Macro to populate form from new row entry (last row)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Can a macro be written to populate a form on a different worksheet from a new row entry on the raw data worksheet?

[image: Macro to populate form from new row entry (last row)]

Comment: Yes it can be done with VBA. Was there anything else to this question?

Comment: (Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: Thank you both for the reply, especially with the tip on how to ask a good question in this forum.  Especially, since this was my first.  To address your question @CallumDA33, yes, there is more to the question I guess.  Would you be able to help with the VBA code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. So, you may either start learning to code yourself and come back every now and then when you are running into bugs / errors or you pay someone to do the coding for you. If you are interested to learn coding yourself then I'd suggest that you start with the [VBA macro recorder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_HQGHPBYoo). Afterwards, have a look at the code and try to understand it by highlighting VBA key-words and pressing `F1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that copies last edited entry from `Data` sheet to `Form` sheet. Put the below code to the `Data` worksheet in your VBA project:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Static objTargetCells As Object
    Dim objTargetCell As Range
    Dim strHeader As Variant
    Dim objTargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long

    Set objTargetSheet = Sheets("Form")

    If objTargetCells Is Nothing Then
        Set objTargetCells = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        x = 1
        Do
            strHeader = Target.Worksheet.Cells(1, x).Value
            Set objTargetCell = objTargetSheet.Cells.Find(strHeader, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, True, , False)
            Set objTargetCells(strHeader) = objTargetCell.Offset(0, 1)
            x = x + 1
        Loop While Cells(1, x).Value <> ""
    End If

    With Target.Worksheet
        If .Cells(1, Target.Column).Value <> "" And Target.Row <> 1 Then
            x = 1
            For Each strHeader In objTargetCells
                objTargetCells(strHeader).Value = .Cells(Target.Row, x).Value
                x = x + 1
            Next
            objTargetSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Here is `Data` worksheet looks like:

[image: Data]

And `Form` worksheet:

[image: Form]

The code runs on every `Data` sheet change event. First time it creates the dictionary of table fields on `Data` sheet, populating it with references to corresponding target cells on the `Form` sheet. These cells are found by `.Find` method, although you can use your ranges hard-coded manually.